# show div when click and hide it when you click again

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

I want to hide and show my div when I click on li. It shows the div but don't hide it.

Here is my link to my code:
[this is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/6nrbzpb4/2/)

> html

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="change(0)">itime1</li>
    <div id="li0">Eshow this</div> 
    <a href="#" onclick="change(1)"><li>item2</li></a>
    <div id="li1">show this</div>
</ul>
```

> css

```
#li0 {
    display:none;
}
#li1 {
    display:none;}
```

> javascript

```
function change(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById('li' + id);
    if (id === 0 || id === 1) {
        if (e.display = "none"){ 
            e.style.display="block";
        }
        else{
            e.style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert this

```
if (e.display = "none")
```

to this

```
if (e.style.display == "none")
```

You need the `.style` and the `==`. You could also use `===`.